# Add "domain admins" group in sudo users

Tags: linux, sudo, administration, sudoedit

I want to give access `domain admins` group to sudoers access. 
I have come across with many commands but nun of works for me.

```
fname.lname ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

With this command i can give access to a particular user, But i want to give access to all the members of the `domain admin` group.

```
%DOMAINNAME\\domain\ admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
%DOMAINNAME\\domain\ admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
%DOM.DOMAINNAME.COM\\domain\ admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
DOMAINNAME\\domain\ admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
DOMAINNAME\\domain\ admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
DOM.DOMAINNAME.COM\\domain\ admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
%DOMAINNAME\\domain_admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Like many commands i have tried but non out of these working.

My domain Group have two words i.e 
    `domain admins`

Complete domain name is like: 
    `DOM.DOMAINNAME.COM`

And short name is 
    `DOMAINNAME`

**Tell me how can i give access to sudoers for a group.**

I am working on python scripting where it asks for sudo run but the user doesn't have `sudo` access or everytime no any domain user is entertain to enter credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked a lot on it, 
And after so many tries and searching **I got this working**

Type the command below and press Enter to safely open the /etc/sudoers file for editing:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

On a new line, insert the text below:

```
%domain\ admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Since I was having DOMAIN name as two words I have to use: `domain\ admins`

```
domain admins
```

This was the exact group name I was having.

**And `%` to specify group. 
and without `%` I would think it is take as username.**

NO NEED TO SPECIFY **DOMAIN** That I was trying before.
i.e:

```
%DOM.DOMAINNAME.COM\\domain\ admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Sometimes it is necessary to use the domain prefix. It depends on the mechanism used to link to the external authenticator, `winbind` or `sssd`. You can see this in the flagged duplicate.

Comment: Oh i can see that.
But in my case i have used `sssd` so it is working fine.